# Php while loop is returning each second value

Tags: php, while-loop

I have such code to get via odbc some data...

```
     $data = odbc_exec($this->odbc_id, $odbc_query);
     odbc_longreadlen($data, 10485760); //10MB = 10485760
     while(odbc_fetch_row($data)) 
     { 
     $row = odbc_fetch_array($data);
     if($row['graphID'] != "") {
     $file_name_jp2 = "TI/" . $table_name . "/" . $row['graphID'] . ".jp2";
     $file = fopen ($file_name_jp2, "w");
     fputs($file, $row['graph']);
     fclose($file);
     set_time_limit(3600);
 }

 unset($row);
 }
```

but for some reasons it is fetching each each second db entrie... But why? What i write wrong?

What to change to fetch all data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using both `odbc_fetch_array` and `odbc_fetch_row`, you should be using one of the other. Something similar to:

```
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($data)) {
  // As you were..
}
```

And remove your line:

```
$row = odbc_fetch_array($data);
```